# Curious feature in GNU Make: Makefile.c

Tags: gnu-make

When there is no Makefile but a Makefile.c, GNU Make automatically tries to:

`cc     Makefile.c   -o Makefile`

and then use that Makefile.

As far as I can see, if Makefile.c contains valid C source then a binary is produced and that binary is not a valid Makefile. If it was not valid source then the process is aborted (no Makefile produced/run). So both cases seem useless.

I tried making a Makefile.asm because assembly can be assembled into a valid Makefile, but this time GNU Make did not recognize the file. (Does the feature only trigger for Makefile.c?)

What is the purpose of this feature?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a consequence of the built-in rules which tell make how to generally make `%` from `%.c` if the latter exists but not the former. It is coincidental and this specific case you are asking about not something clever you should spend effort on trying to understand.

(Though I suppose it could be a fun corner case to exploit if you wanted to participate in the [International Obfuscated C Code Contest](https://www.ioccc.org/).)

Comment: Similar in some sense to how marvellously `cat food` will happen to do something if you have a file named `food`, or `make love` will execute the commands for the target `love` if you have a Makefile with a target with that name.

Comment: It's a combination of this, plus the GNU make facility that attempts to automatically update all parsed makefiles including the main makefile and all included makefiles: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html